# Add Camera button to UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios

I would like to add a camera button to `UIImagePickerController` (same size of photos), place it at the position of 1st image shown (just like the screenshot below):

[image]

I am thinking of using a `UICollectionView` combined with `UINavigationBar` / `UINavigationController` / `UIToolbar`, but sounds like I'm re-inventing the wheel. Is there any quick way to just add the camera button?

Comment: Its obviously a custom control shown in the image, you need to use CollectionView and create it.

Comment: No You dont have that option. Re invent the wheel :-)